# how to run react js. code on visual studio code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio, react-redux

was formally using sublime text to run react js. codes, recently i tried changing my IDE to visual studio code but have being getting errors. need to know the procedures for running react codes on visual studio code

Comment: Visual Studio Code isn't the thing running your code, nor was Sublime Text. What were you doing previously, what are you doing now? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

First u need to understand how it all waorks.
To run your js code u need a browser and notepad.

U need to create html document and add js script code f.e.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Hello world");

</script>
```

If u want to run use React framework, i suggest you to start with https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

It will create all necessary (basics) scripts for you. Than u will be able to run your website/components/js w/e via terminal script, and it will be display in your browser under localhost.